# Как оформить отступы в treeview

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, style, treeview

Есть набор элементов div, формирующий собой некоторый кастомный treeview

```
<div data-level="0" class="has_child"></div>
<div data-level="1" class="has_child"></div>
<div data-level="2"></div>
<div data-level="1" class="has_child"></div>
<div data-level="2"></div>
<div data-level="0"></div>
```

С помощью JS задается свойство padding в зависимости от уровня вложенности элемента

```
some_view.$el.css('padding-left', level * 6 + '%')
```

В результате получается вполне рабочая древовидная структура элементов. Но проблема в том, что элементов может быть очень много и при прокрутке будет трудно отследить уровень вложенности. Мне бы хотелось на месте padding'a реализовать индикатор уровня вложенности. Как пример - дерево комментариев на хабре:
[image: comments]

У кого есть какие идеи как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Почему сложно определить уровень вложенности при прокрутке? У Вас же она задается через data-атрибут у элемента?

Comment: Я имел ввиду сложно для пользователя. Не хватает наглядности без индикатора. Я сомневаюсь что пользователь будет открывать инспектор в браузере и читать data-атрибуты)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете расположить слева от тела элемента дерева пустой див, у которого установлен `background`:

```
.tree {
    background: transparent url("img.png") repeat-x;
}
```

Выставляя с помощью js ширину этого дива пропорционально ширине картинки, фон будет повторяться. Благодаря этому и получится эффект глубины дерева.

Можно сделать еще так. Делайте так, чтобы каждый вложенный элемент дерева был внутри родительского дива. Добавьте к каждому вложенному элементу `margin-left: npx`. Так же добавляете к каждому вложенному элементу слева блок примерно с такими свойствами:

```
.tree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 500px;
    background: transparent url("img.png") repeat-x;
}
```

Естественно у самого внешнего контейнера надо добавить: `overflow: hidden;`. Вуаля.

Comment: Второй вариант с вложенными дивами мне не подходит, так как на каждый див из списка вешается JQueryUI.draggable и тогда при перетаскивании за родителем потянутся все дочерние элементы.

В случае с первым вариантом: как мне тогда расположить .tree и div на одной строке без использования какого-либо элемента-обертки над ними?(чтобы не нарушать тот же draggable)

Comment: `<div data-level="0" class="has_child"><div class="tree"></div><div class="content"></div></div>`. Вложить `.tree` внутрь, а на одной строке с контентом это уже ерунда) И draggable будет спокоен.